# JAVA : Ignoring the space at the beigining of a string read from file((splitting that first space))

Tags: java, split

In Java , I want to read a string from file but I need to ignore if the string contains space at the beginning.

For example:

```
//1 space// what //more than 1 space// 893
```

The output must be:

```
what 893
```

only one space between them and their is no space at the begining

I tried method: `String.split()` but it didn't split more than one space.

Comment: Regex is your friend. Why didn't you ignore "what"? There's a space before it, can you please explain?

Comment: 1) I want to start reading the string when it finds the first alphabet character and ignore if there's a space at the beginning.
2) And to read the next part after certain no. of spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a pattern such as `"\\s*(\\S+)\\s+(\\d+)"`. That would be any optional whitepace followed by a group of non-whitespace characters then any (consecutive) whitespace and finally a group of digits. Like this,

```
String in = "  what    893";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\S+)\\s+(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.printf("%s %s%n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

Output is

```
what 893
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
s="  what    893";
s = s.replaceAll("^\s+","");
s = s.replaceAll("\s+"," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `String.trim()` to remove the leading space

Answer (score 0):

You first can replace all multiple spaces with single space and then do the required operation.

```
String newString = originalString.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
// perform required operation on newString
```